# How to use Hensel Lifting to solve $x^2\equiv 2\pmod {17^3}$?

Tags: number-theory

I got $x^2\equiv 2\pmod {17} \iff x\equiv\pm \sqrt{2} \pmod {17}$.

Then, $x^2 \equiv 2\pmod {289}$.

$(\sqrt 2 + 17y)^2\equiv 2\pmod {289}$

Then I got

$34\sqrt 2\equiv 0\pmod {289}$

I am stuck from this part! Can someone please help me out with that.

Comment: That is some shocking $\LaTeX$. You can use \sqrt{x} for $\sqrt{x}$ and \pm for $\pm$

Comment: I've edited it. ${}$

Comment: You probably want to compute an integer value for $\sqrt{2}$ rather than treating it symbolically. Anyways, what is the actual Hensel's lemma say? That should say what to do next! It would be easier to help if you explain more precisely where your troubles are. Anyways, I think you have lost a $y$ in your arithmetic....

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564683/how-to-use-the-method-of-hensel-lifting-to-solve-x2-x-1-equiv-0-pmod-11 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307514/hensel-lifting-and-solving-with-mods

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;x^2=2\pmod{17}\implies x=\pm 6\pmod{17}\\{}\\
\bullet&\;\;\text{Since}\;\;f'(6)=(x^2-2)'|_{x=6}=2\cdot 6=12\neq 0\pmod{17}\;,\;\text{we can apply Hensel's lemma:}\\{}\\
\bullet&\;\;t:=-\frac{f(6)}{17}(f'(6))^{-1}=-\frac{34}{17}12^{-1}=-2\cdot10=14\pmod {17}\implies\\{}\\
\bullet&\;\;s:=6+14\cdot 17=244\;\;\text{is a root of}\;\;x^2=2\pmod{17^2}\end{align*}$$

Repeat the above for $\;17^3\;$:

$$r:=-\frac{f(244)}{17^2}(f'(6))'=-206\cdot 12^{-1}=$$

$$=-206\cdot265=31\pmod{17^2=289}\implies$$

$$ s:=244+31\cdot 289=244+4046=4290\pmod{17^3=4913}\;\;\text{is one of the wanted roots}$$

Repeat the above with all the roots you find in the way ($\;-6\pmod {17}\;,\;-244\pmod{289}\;$  etc.)